# OCR Space API Python Not Printing Text

Tags: python

I am trying to send an image to `ocr.space` using their api with python. Here is my code. The code runs without errors but doesn't print anything. Why? How can I make it `print`??

```
import requests
import json

def ocr_space_file(filename, overlay=False, api_key='helloworld', language='eng'):
    """ OCR.space API request with local file.
        Python3.5 - not tested on 2.7
       :param filename: Your file path & name.
       :param overlay: Is OCR.space overlay required in your response.
                Defaults to False.
       :param api_key: 2fe3ae129e88957
                Defaults to 'helloworld'.
       :param language: Language code to be used in OCR.
                List of available language codes can be found on https://ocr.space/OCRAPI
                Defaults to 'en'.
       :return: Result in JSON format.
    """

    payload = {'isOverlayRequired': overlay,
           'apikey': api_key,
           'language': language,
           }
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        r = requests.post('https://api.ocr.space/parse/image',
                      files={filename: f},
                      data=payload,
                      )
    return r.content.decode()


def ocr_space_url(url, overlay=False, api_key='helloworld', language='eng'):
    """ OCR.space API request with remote file.
        Python3.5 - not tested on 2.7
    :param url: Image url.
    :param overlay: Is OCR.space overlay required in your response.
                Defaults to False.
    :param api_key: 2fe3ae129e88957
                Defaults to 'helloworld'.
    :param language: Language code to be used in OCR.
                List of available language codes can be found on https://ocr.space/OCRAPI
                Defaults to 'en'.
    :return: Result in JSON format.
    """

    payload = {'url': url,
           'isOverlayRequired': overlay,
           'apikey': api_key,
           'language': language,
           }
    m = r.content.decode()
    jsonstr = json.loads(m)
    print (jsonstr["ParsedResults"][0]["ParsedText"])

ocr_space_file(filename='example_image.png', language='eng')
```

Here is a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/E7M5WWXC) to my code.

Comment: you have only one `print` and this print is in `ocr_space_url()` function, but you don't call this function anywhere

Comment: I fixed it. I fixed the last line in the code. Here is my new last line- (ocr_space_file(filename='example_image.png', language='eng'))

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I fixed the last line in the code. Here is my new last line- (ocr_space_file(filename='example_image.png', language='eng'))